# ¿Cómo enviar un object por ajax a php?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

Quiero mandar los datos de una datatable a través de `ajax` pero en el controlador de php me llega el array vacío.

Dejo mi código :

```
datos = table.rows().data();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: base_url + "index.php/Admin/UpdatePrecioVenta",
    data: datos,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
      loading();
    },
    complete: function() {
      loading();
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#cambios").val("0");
      alertas("success", data.mensaje);
      url = base_url + "index.php/Articulo/listadoArticulos"
      table.ajax.url(url).load();
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alertas("Ocurrio un error: " + error);
    }
  });
```

y en **php** :

```
 public function UpdatePrecioVenta()
{
    $datos = $this->input->post();
    var_dump($datos);
    $response = $this->admin_model->ActualizarPrecioVenta($datos);
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: Si `datos` tiene algun dato, intenta enviando con `JSON.stringify(table.rows().data())`

Comment: me genera el siguiente error : Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON